# AWS CloudWatch rule schedule has irregular intervals (when it shouldn't)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

There is an Elastic Container Service cluster running an application internally referred to as Deltaload. It checks the data in Oracle production database and in dev database in Amazon RDS and loads whatever is missing into RDS. A CloudWatch rule is set up to trigger this process every hour.

Now, for some reason, every 20-30 hours there is one interval of a different length. Normally, it is a ~25 min gap, but on other occasions it can be 80-90 min instead of 60. I could understand a difference of 1-2 minutes, but being off by 30 min from an hourly schedule sounds really problematic, especially given the full run takes ~45 min. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be the reason for that? Or at least how can I figure out why it is so?

The interesting part is that this glitch in schedule either breaks or fixes the Deltaload app. What I mean is, if it is running successfully every hour for a whole day and then the 20 min interval happens, it will then be crashing every hour for the next day until the next glitch arrives, after which it will work again (the very same process, same container, same everything). It crashes, because the connection to RDS times out. This 'day of crashes, day of runs' thing has been going on since early February. I am not too proficient with AWS. This Deltaload app is written in C#, which I don't know. The only thing I managed to do is to increase the RDS connection timeout to 10 min, which did not fix the problem. The guy that wrote the app has left the company a time ago and is unavailable. There are no other developers on this project, as everyone got fired, because of corona. So far, the best alternative I see, is to just rewrite the whole thing in Python (which I know). If anyone has any other thoughts on how understand/fix it, I'd greatly appreciate any input.

To restate my actual question: why is it that CloudWatch rule drops in irregular intervals in a regular schedule? How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What does your expression look like?

Comment: @mokugo-devops could you please clarify which expression you mean exactly? I googled `cloudwatch expression`, but only found stuff related to plotting metrics on the cloudwatch graph.

Comment: I am presuming if you say schedule you mean there is a cron expression being used by your CloudWatch rule

Comment: @mokugo-devops, you can either config a rule with a cron expression or you can tick the "fixed rate" box and specify the rate. I believe this is how it was configured - fixed rate of one hour.

Comment: Ah, I am not quite sure exactly why that would be. But if you want it at a specific time try looking at a cron schedule `cron(0 * * * * *)`

Comment: @mokugo-devops, ok, thank you for the tip! I'll try configuring it through a cron expression to see if this will help.

Comment: Hope it works :)